# Block Soft Panel Input language switch

Tags: windows-phone-7, on-screen-keyboard

How to make the on-screen keyboard use only English, even if the settings are selected some other languages ​​besides English?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, you cannot change the keyboard language in code on WP7.

*Update*

I did a bit of research on pulling the current language (Locale) from the app thread and came up with this post on in-app language selection in code. This looks like it was designed to localize text, however, I have a hunch the keyboard language will follow suit. Good Luck!

http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2011/07/mvvmlight-based-language-selection-for.html

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(CurrentLanguage.Locale);
      Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
```

Comment: Perhaps there is way to check language button was clicked?

Comment: Unfortunately switching language on keyboard does not affect on Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture and Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture properties

Comment: I need to prevent input non-latin characters in TextBox